# OS X Snow Leopard Server SVN WebDav setup issue

Tags: svn, mac-osx, webdav

I followed this article (http://agileshrugged.com/blog/?p=14) to setup my SVN server on OS X Server 10.6.2. I'm trying to use the web based service instead of svn+ssh.

The problem is when I get to the step to change the confi file, there is no actual tag. It's a tag. So I assumed that was fine and made the adjustments to it as the article recommends. I then change DAV Off to DAV svn.

Whenever I reset the server and try accessing the server address I get a server error.

It's very, very annoying!

David

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working on my Mac OS X Server after some minor modifications.

I wrote a [blog post](http://brockwoolf.com/blog/subversion-server-on-mac-os-x-leopard-server) explaining what worked for me. It might help you with your problem.